# Web app for mobile and desktop PC

Tags: android, asp.net, ios, mobile, cordova

I want to develop web applications for both mobile and desktop(PC). After goggling i found no framework other than Phonegap but phonegap only compiles mobile apps i want to extend the functionality to desktop(PC) using **asp.net** . So that i can create a common application that will run on mobile as well as desktop. My aim is to create an offline application(wont mind using a web browser as a platform for running app on desktop). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the functionality you want to offer.  The company I work for started with native Android and iOS apps before we moved to using HTML5/Javascript web apps that work across all platforms.

HTML5 allows offline capabilities using the appcache as well as browser storage using websql and indexedDB.  Its worth considering, however, that it is not possible to access things like phonebooks, or the camera without the use of a framework like phonegap/cordova

I'd recommend checking out [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) if you want a one size fits all approach.  Or a responsive framework like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 1):

If you said you don't mind using just web browser, why don't you just create your entire system in web, and write few separate applications that is literally a sized web-browser that auto directs you to your service website?

For desktop, you can use any language that just to make a windowed web-browser, OR just write an alias that auto open the default browser and go to that url.

For mobile: android and iphone both supports:
- make an alias for a web link
- or easily make an app that is just a web browser, or with some additional feature on top(like just a menu view before your webview), although not sure if the verification process would be easy if you just got a pure webview for you App